# Can you prove recurrent relations on integrals by taking derivative of both sides of the equation?

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations, reduction-formula

As an example let$$\qquad I_n = \int x^n\cos x\,dx\qquad(1).$$ By performing integration by parts we can prove the following:
$$I_n = x^n\sin x+ nx^{n–1}\cos x– n(n – 1)I_{n–2}\qquad (2).$$ However, my question is if we are told to prove this relation can we take the derivative of both sides of $(2)$ to prove it? And if so would I say that this proof is by the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: Yes, no doubts.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: what do you get when you differentiate $x^n\sin x+nx^{n-1}\cos x$?

Comment: you will get $$nx^{n-1}sin x + x^n cos x + n(n-1)x^{n-2} cos x - n x^{n-1}sinx$$ My worry is that if I can use this as proof then what's stopping me from saying 1=2 because if I differentiate both sides I get 0 = 0. Is it the fact that there is an integral in the equation? Basically what I'm asking is what has to hold for me to be able to use this line of reasoning. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, right. It sounds like what you need to review is the difference between using definite & indefinite integrals in IBP.

Comment: The proof you are describing works, but does not require the fundamental theorem of calculus,. This is because the integrals you are using are indefinite, which means rather than being defined by Riemann or Lebesgue or Kurzweil, they are anti-derivatives. That is, $I_n$ is by definition the class of functions whose derivative is $x^n\cos x$. Indefinite integrals are tied to definite integrals by the FTC, but to their derivatives just by definition.